How do I solve CORS issues with the Zoho Expense Report API?
In my project where I use Angular 16, I want to use the Zoho Expense APIs, specifically the expense report API. Since I am using Angular, I created a client-based application and obtained my Client ID, from which I generated an access token. Using this documentation (https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v6/get-users.html), I successfully retrieved the users in my Angular app.
However, I am unable to retrieve expense reports using this documentation (https://www.zoho.com/expense/api/v1/expense-reports/#overview). I am encountering a CORS error. I have checked the headers and I am sending "X-com-zoho-expense-organizationid", content type, and authorization as my access token. My scope also includes "ZohoExpense.fullaccess.ALL". While the API works correctly when I make the request from Postman, it gives an error in my Angular app.
Do you have a possible solution for this?
network headers
I have tried all the different methods including the documentation. But couldn't solve the problem.

I solved the problem; unfortunately, you cannot call Zoho APIs other than CRM from the client side. What needs to be done here is to create a server and send requests to the Zoho APIs through this server. I solved the problem by creating a Lambda function.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
